# Simplifying code as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am still working on a project with pies. Going to the next level. Now I have this code that is repeating all the time and i am trying to make it simple and less code. So this code is repeated for pie 2 till 12. When I trie to use the toString command for the pie_mc i get an error that it 's not working for the MovieClip symbol. How can I solve this?

```
if(counter == 2) {
  pie_mc = pie2_mc;
  //pie_mc = "pie" + counter.toString()+"_mc";
  pie_mc.visible = true;
  for (i=1; i <= counter; i++){
    partx_mc = "t"+ counter.toString()+"_p"+i.toString()+"_mc";
    pie_mc[partx_mc].alpha = 0.6;
    pie_mc[partx_mc].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showPiepart);       
    }
}
if(counter == 3) {
  pie_mc = pie3_mc;
  //pie_mc = "pie" + counter.toString()+"_mc";
  pie_mc.visible = true;
  for (i=1; i <= counter; i++){
    partx_mc = "t"+ counter.toString()+"_p"+i.toString()+"_mc";
    pie_mc[partx_mc].alpha = 0.6;
    pie_mc[partx_mc].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showPiepart);       
    }
}
```

In dutch: 1067: Impliciete afgedwongen omzetting van een waarde van het type String in een niet-gerelateerd type flash.display:MovieClip.
- Implicit transform of a value of type string in a MovieClip.

Comment: You can't set a movie clip to a string value. Partx_mc is a movie clip right?  Movie clips have width and height and scale and x and y coordinates etc.  how can you make a string equal a movie clip? Strings don't have width or height or x and y coordinates so how can they be equal? Are you trying to use a string value to pick a movie clip by the movie clips instance name?

Comment: That's the funny thing. It does work for the partx_mc as part of the pie and yes that is a MovieClip, but when i trie it for the pie itself it does not work.

Comment: "When I try it for the pie itself it doesn't work..." so is that where the problem is? Why haven't you shown that part of your code if that's where the problem is?

Comment: I did not put it there because that's not working and so I am how I can simplify this. I have 100 lines of code now for 12 pies... I put it in now to make the question more complete. I am dutch so I translated the error 1067.

Comment: Well in order to see what is similar and therefore excessive in your code, we need to see at least two of the 12 blocks of code.

Comment: Ok. Well it's almost the same... (:

Comment: `pie_mc[partx_mc].alpha = 0.6;` does this work? It seems odd. `pie_mc` isn't an array is it?

Comment: And even if pie_mc were an array your value in the [] is not an integer. So that's another problem. You know, I don't think I can help much more without getting the complete picture of what you are trying to do. There are too many mistakes here for me to see obviously what your goal is.